# Is it necessary to call delete[] vs delete for char arrays?

Tags: c++

I'm utilizing a library written by a collegue and discovered that `valgrind` was spewing out errors related to the `delete`.

The problem was that there were allocations of char arrays like

```
char* s = new char[n];
```

followed up later with `delete s`

instead of `delete[] s`

He tells me that the difference is really that `delete[] s` will call a destructor for the object at each position in `s` (if it has one), in this case it doesn't because it's a primitive type.  I believe that is true.

So delete s is not really a bug as such and `valgrind` is just being very thorough.

Will it still definitely free all the memory associated with `s`?

Comment: ................yes.  RTFM, no offense.

Comment: RTBA - Read the below answers. They contradict your what you just said. - no offence.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If you allocate an array using `new[]`, you have to destroy it using `delete[]`. In general, the functions `operator delete(void*)` and `operator delete[](void*)` aren't guaranteed to be the same.

Refer [here](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/freestore-mgmt#delete-array-built-ins)

Comment: I would change `new` to `new[]` to reduce confusion.

Comment: while you're fixing typos, I'm pretty sure you meant `operator delete` instead of `operation delete`.

Answer (score 9):

Forget about destructors. The difference between `new/delete` and `new[]/delete[]` is that these are two completely unrelated, independent memory allocation mechanisms. They cannot be mixed. Using `delete` to deallocate memory allocated with `new[]` is no different than using `free` for the same purpose.

Comment: +1 -- this is how you have to think about it, but in reality there's usually little difference in the allocated memory itself.

Answer (score 8):

The standard says nothing about how the memory will get deleted -- it merely says that to not match the correct new with the correct delete is undefined behavior.

Actually, `new[]` followed by `delete` usually frees all the memory that was allocated with `new[]`, but destructors for the items in that array are not called correctly. (Most of the time -- not that the standard mandates that)

Rather than dynamically allocated arrays, you should consider use of `vector`.

Comment: +1: `std::vector` (or possibly `std::string`) is almost certainly the better answer.

Comment: It would be but this is a custom string class with no external dependencies. Done for compiled size reasons.

Comment: @Matt H.: I seriously doubt you're going to beat `std::vector` for compiled size.

Comment: If there are destructors, `new[]` is all but guaranteed to return a pointer that does not point to an allocation block. `operator delete` might tolerate getting a pointer a few bytes into the block, or it might not.

Comment: @billy, as I've said, it's not my library.  For good reason, the entire stdc++ was not allowed to be used in order to produce very small binaries.

Comment: @Matt H: As I said, I seriously doubt you're going to beat std::vector with your own code. But good luck :)