# Delete char array. Alternative way?

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it necessary to call delete[] vs delete for char arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3681084/is-it-necessary-to-call-delete-vs-delete-for-char-arrays)

```
char *p = new char[200];

delete p;
```

This kind of (I changed var name) code is from a big commercial project.

The third line. Is this right?
Should I change it or leave it there. Coz no bug report for this and this programs runs more than 4  years.

Thanks.

Comment: The fact that it has been running in production for 4 years means that you've had a memory leak in production for 4 years.

Comment: A lot of leaks are bening. If you don't do allocation repeatedly nobody will notice it.

Comment: what is wrong with std::vector<char>

Comment: @yi_H: (technically its not a leak but incorrect deletion). But these can (as you say) be benign, **until** you upgrade your compiler or runtime and then suddenly it may start crashing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You **have** to use `delete[]` since you used `new[]`, it's not an alternative.

```
delete [] p;
```

Comment: so This is definitely a bug. Even on WIndows, visual studio compiler.[I assume it has some optimization]

Comment: It happens to work with Visual Studio, because the compiler generates identical code for `delete` and `delete[]` for types without a destructor, like `char`. It is still a bug though, even if it passes all test cases.

Comment: @David: Like Martin said in the question comments, why not just use a `std::vector<char>`?

Answer (score 3):

- If `new` uses `[]`, delete must it as well:

  ```
  T *p = new T[100];
  delete [] p; //correct
  delete p   ; //incorrect
  ```
- If `new` doesn't use `[]`, delete must not use it as well:

  ```
  T *p = new T;
  delete [] p; //incorrect
  delete p   ; //correct
  ```

Incorrect doesn't mean that you will get compilation error; neither does it mean that the program must fail at runtime. It means, the program behavior is undefined; anything could be possible, and most likely there will be memory leak.

Answer (score 2):

In theory, to follow the standard, line 3 should read `delete[] p;`.

But, in practice this has no implication, as the destructor of char does nothing.

Indeed, the difference between the delete and the array delete, is that with array delete, the destructor is called as many times as there are objects. With the regular delete, the destructor is called only once.

In the end, you should replace it with `delete[] p;`

Answer (score 1):

You allocated an array with `operator new[]`. You must balance that with `operator delete[]`, *not* `operator delete`:

```
delete[] p;
```